# Application cannot be exported due to the error(s) below

Tags: android, eclipse, export, project

I get error when export project in android eclipse

[image: eclipse Application cannot be exported due to the error(s) below.]

Comment: The error message is clear : "Project has compilation errors". Means you have to fix your compilation errors in order to be able to export.

Comment: you can not export your application unless you solve all your errors ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are confident that there aren't any errors, do Project > clean (at least in Eclipse)